# Computationally binding commitment

Tags: reference-request, commitments

A Computationally Binding commitment scheme is defined as a tuple of protocols $(\mathsf{Keygen}, \mathsf{Com}, \mathsf{Open})$, that along with correctness guarantees that for all PPT algorithms the probability that, given a correctly generated commitment key $k$, it outputs a commitment and two different openings is negligible.

Now, if the receiver sends a message $R$ between the committing phase and the opening phase, called $m$ the message revealed, then it's almost never the case that $m$ and $R$ are independent (with negligible probability the adversary could open to a function of $R$). Can we at least say that $m$ and $R$ are "almost independent" (in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774710/relaxing-statistical-independence) I proposed a way to have relaxed independence)?

In case the answer is negative, what are computationally binding commitments used for?

Comment: Why is it an issue that R and m are not independent? Btw, this has nothing to do with computational binding. In fact computational binding is *necessary* if you want independence, since you can only get independence if the commitment is perfectly *hiding*.

Comment: I'm unsure of what independence you are refering to in the last sentence, anyway consider for example an auction protocol where $A$ commits to $a$ and then $B$ commits $b$. Whoever is the last one to open its commitment have a __small__ probability to modify the opening value to be greater than the opponent's one. How can you argue security then?

Comment: Another example. In a $ZK$ protocol $\mathcal{V}(x,w)$ begin committing to some $m_1$, then the prover sends a $m_2$ and the verifier replies opening $m_1$ and doing other things. Now in general (but a good example is the protocol of page 36 in https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/552.pdf) to argue computational soundness you need that the commitment is computationally hiding, but to argue even just computationally zero knowledge I'm not sure if computationally bindingness is enough.

If you can prove me wrong with an example i'd be happy

Comment: Not sure I understand the question exactly, but are you interested in commitment schemes that are secure under a notion of composition called *concurrent composition*, as discussed for example, [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2001/055).